# How do you test dependency injection in angular?

Tags: testing, angularjs, dependency-injection

I use typescript and angular. 
So for example in controllers I have notation

a)

```
export function Controller($scope: Scope) {}
(<any>Controller).$inject = ['$scope'];
```

b)

```
export class Controller {
    constructor(private $scope) {} 
}
App.directive('someCoolDirective', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  etc...
  controller: <any[]>['$scope', SomeCoolDirective.Controller],
  etc...
};
```

});

c)

```
App.directive('someDirectives', <any[]>[ '$parse', '$rootScope', '$compile',     'userPermissions', function($parse, $rootScope, $compile, userPermissions) { }
```

d)

```
services...
```

As you see there are different ways of specifing dependencies for DI after minification. 
But we are only humans, I tend to forget   (Controller).$inject, or I add some dependency and forgot to add in array. If I don't specify it, it works, till minification. Than it is pain in the neck to find it out. Sometimes there is even no error in browser console.

**Do you know some tool, that checks all controllers,services, directives and verifies that there is correct $inject ['$scope',... etc.] notation?** That it matches all required dependencies? I want to automate in on out build server.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you hack the Typescript compiler and do it yourself? Then publish it somewhere (e.g. Github) so that it's usable for poor people like me ;)

Comment: Just kidding. Poor man solution is to use regexes. I'll write it probably some day for you ;)